# Finding exact information retrieved by Installers

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, installation

While installing some software via installers or web installers, I want to find out all the data that the app retrieves from my machine (eg machine name, OS type, IP address, MAC address etc) and sends it to its server.

Is there any tool that will help me find out what data does the app retrieve while installation or when it is active and sends to its server?

Comment: Without access to the script file that created these installers what you want is outside of your reach once the installer is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is monitor the installer/app using something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) for registry and file activity, and a protocol analyzer/packet sniffer such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) for data being transmitted back "home" to a server. Of course, the data transmitted might be encrypted or otherwise transformed, so don't always expect plain-text to be captured that you can easily analyse.